How do I drag my Excel formula horizontally across and vertically down, with dynamic reference (every third cell)?
How do I drag my Excel formula horizontally across and vertically down, with dynamic reference (every third cell)?
For example,
The data is available as follows (in Row 1, in multiple Columns A,B,C...):

I wanted to offset/jump cell every third cell and in the following format through formula:


Adapt the formula below. It combines TOCOL and WRAPROWS functions This assumes that you have Excel365.
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:K1,1),2)



With traditional functions
in cell A5:
=OFFSET($A$1,,(ROW()-5)*3+COLUMN()-1)
in the formula value 5 is the row number where the first formula is placed. Then drag to the right and down.

